# My dog has had staples in his foot about a week now & I want to know if it’s alright if there’s dog hair on the staples

Tags: dogs, surgery

I have been usually keeping the foot bandaged but I’ve left it uncovered for about a day or so due to the bandage moving & causing irritation. is it okay that there’s dog hair on the staples? I’ve been keeping it wrapped when we go outside but unwrapped inside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's okay if there are a few hairs on the wound, but if it's being left uncovered (which is fine at this point when inside), you can also start cleaning it once or twice a day with a clean cloth moistened with warm, soapy water, then dried, especially if it also looks a bit dirty. That will decrease the chance of infection, though for a wound to start getting infected this far out is pretty unusual.